# Confusion about the extern keyword and multiple source files

Tags: c, extern

I am trying to fully understand how extern works, so I created 3 files, two of them are source files and the last is a header file. This is what is contained in each of them:
testingfile1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "testingheader.h"
int main() {
    change();
    int my_extern;
    printf("\n%d", my_extern);
    return 0;

}
```

testingfile2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "testingheader.h"
void change() {
    int my_extern;

    my_extern = 15;
    printf("%d", my_extern);
}
```

testingheader.h:

```
#if !defined(TESTINGHEADER_H)
#define TESTINGHEADER_H

#include <stdio.h>
extern int my_extern;
void change();

#endif
```

The output of this program is: 15 0. However, I thought that since my_extern is an extern int, if you were to change to the value in one source file, it's value would be changed in all of the other source files. Is this not how extern works, or am I doing something wrong in the code itself?

Comment: Compile again with `-Wshadow` enabled in your compile string for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS. The compiler will identify exactly where the issues are.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases remove `int my_extern;` where you have it, because those become local variables which happen to have the same name `my_extern`.

`extern int my_extern;` just means there's an int called `my_extern` "out there somewhere".  So you'd have to declare `int my_extern` somewhere at file scope, for example like this:

```
int my_extern = 0;

void change() {
    my_extern = 15;
    printf("%d", my_extern);
}
```

Comment: Declaring `my_extern` global - it is initialized to zero by default. Simply `int my_extern;`

Comment: Fair point, the `= 0` was superfluous if the initial value should be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

In testingfile2.c, the `my_extern` variable is local to the function and you are not seeing the global `my_extern` that the extern command is referencing.  Of course, you don't *have* a global `my_extern`, so that is another problem.  You would get a linker error if you actually tried to reference the global `my_extern` that the extern command is referencing.

Comment: I could be wrong on this but someone told me that, if you have a bunch of `extern` declarations but never instantiate it, the linker will pick one of the declarations to be **it**.  Once again, I could be wrong about that.

Comment: @DanielWalker -- That might be compiler / linker dependent, but I've never heard of it nor have I tried it.  I would think that declaring a variable as extern and then never using it would get optimized out by the compiler, same way that unused functions might get optimized out by the compiler or linker.  As such, it would be entirely compiler dependent.  I just tested it with the gcc compiler on my PC and the linker gives an "undefined reference" error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're re-declaring `int my_extern;` inside your functions.  Therefore, C treats that as a separate variable from the global `my_extern`.

The statement `extern int my_extern;` is a declaration that a global `int` called `my_extern` will be declared somewhere.  You haven't done that.  Instead, you've created local `my_extern` variables.